# jquery post() response not comparing to string

Tags: jquery, post, compare

in advance thanks for your help, I'm having a problem with the response of a post(), when trying to compare it with a string, my code is:

```js
$.post( "cand.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>", { accion: "eliminar"})
 .done(function(data) {
  console.log ($.type(data));
  console.log (data);
  console.log (data === 'ok');
 });
```

and my console answers are:

> string
>
> ok
>
> false

as you cas see the data var is a string with value of "ok" but when I compare it with a string, it's false

Comment: what's the length of data?

Comment: after aplying data.lengh it says 4

Comment: Since the length is 4 looks like there are spaces around. Try `$.trim(data) === 'ok'`.

Comment: it looks that there is a break line before the ok, the console is printing the ok with a first line in blank

Comment: getting whitespace returned from server...trim as mentioned, or use json

Comment: sending the answer in json and parsing it work!! thanks!!!!